# Source code of receiving email

Tags: asp.net

I am making email client in asp.net C#. In it, GridView is not taking data of more than 5 rows. I am having 250 mails in my mailbox. But GridView is not showing that data. It is showing only up to 5 rows and after that five to six rows data are presented out of the GridView.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("[id*=lnkView]").live("click", function () {
    var subject = $(this).text();
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $("#body").html($(".body", row).html());
    $("#attachments").html($(".Attachments", row).html());
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: subject,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmails" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="MessageNumber"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="From" DataField="From" HtmlEncode="false" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text='<%#           Eval("Subject") %>' />
            <span class="body" style="display: none">
                <%# Eval("Body") %></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DateSent" />
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="Attachments">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptAttachments" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAttachment" runat="server" OnClick="Download" Text='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <br>
                </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<span id="body"></span>
<br />
<span id="attachments"></span>
</div>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected List<Email> Emails
{
    get { return (List<Email>)ViewState["Emails"]; }
    set { ViewState["Emails"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Read_Emails();
    }
}

private void Read_Emails()
{
    Pop3Client pop3Client;
    if (Session["Pop3Client"] == null)
    {
        pop3Client = new Pop3Client();
        pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
        pop3Client.Authenticate("example@gmail.com", "password", AuthenticationMethod.TryBoth);
        Session["Pop3Client"] = pop3Client;
    }
    else
    {
        pop3Client = (Pop3Client)Session["Pop3Client"];
    }
    int count = pop3Client.GetMessageCount();
    this.Emails = new List<Email>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i);
        Email email = new Email()
        {
            MessageNumber = i,
            Subject = message.Headers.Subject,
            DateSent = message.Headers.DateSent,
            From = string.Format("<a href = 'mailto:{1}'>{0}</a>", message.Headers.From.DisplayName, message.Headers.From.Address),
        };
        MessagePart body = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();
        if (body != null)
        {
            email.Body = body.GetBodyAsText();
        }
        else
        {
            body = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
            if (body != null)
            {
                email.Body = body.GetBodyAsText();
            }
        }
        List<MessagePart> attachments = message.FindAllAttachments();

        foreach (MessagePart attachment in attachments)
        {
            email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
            {
                FileName = attachment.FileName,
                ContentType = attachment.ContentType.MediaType,
                Content = attachment.Body
            });
        }
        this.Emails.Add(email);
        counter++;
        if (counter > count)
        {
            break;
        }
        gvEmails.DataSource = this.Emails;
        gvEmails.DataBind();
    }
    //gvEmails.DataSource = this.Emails;
    //gvEmails.DataBind();
}
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Repeater rptAttachments = (e.Row.FindControl("rptAttachments") as Repeater);
        List<Attachment> attachments = this.Emails.Where(email => email.MessageNumber == Convert.ToInt32(gvEmails.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value)).FirstOrDefault().Attachments;
        rptAttachments.DataSource = attachments;
        rptAttachments.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkAttachment = (sender as LinkButton);
    GridViewRow row = (lnkAttachment.Parent.Parent.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
    List<Attachment> attachments = this.Emails.Where(email => email.MessageNumber == Convert.ToInt32(gvEmails.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value)).FirstOrDefault().Attachments;
    Attachment attachment = attachments.Where(a => a.FileName == lnkAttachment.Text).FirstOrDefault();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + attachment.FileName);
    Response.ContentType = attachment.ContentType;
    Response.BinaryWrite(attachment.Content);
    Response.End();
}
}

[Serializable]

public class Email
{
public Email()
{
    this.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
}
public int MessageNumber { get; set; }
public string From { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Body { get; set; }
public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Attachment
{
public string FileName { get; set; }
public string ContentType { get; set; }
public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And, do you think that your problems with the GridView are due to the fact that you are using it to display emails? Or would you have the same problems if you asked it to display Contacts? Or Orders? Or Cities?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is becuase of using emails

Comment: But you would have the same problem if it were not email.

Comment: @JohnSaunders When proivding my gmail address that is having ten mails in it. So gridview work perfectly showing all the mails in grid. But When I provide my other gmail address having 250 mails. Then in result eleven emails are shown and in gridview only five emails are shown and remainning six are out of gridview. Its totally out of knowledge. Can you please get me rid out of this problem.

Comment: I mean that your problem is about the number of items in the grid.  It is not important that the items are emails. Try changing the data source of the grid to a static list of items. That will eliminate the database as a source of the problem. If you have the same problem with different data, then you know that the problem is the grid code.

Comment: Have not understand your words. Cannot you provide me the links? So that I can understand from there.